# Jquery: Getting input value of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have the following code:

```
  <form action="" method="get" onsubmit="doRequest($('word').value); $('word').value=''; return false;">
    <input type="text" name="word" id="word" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
```

doRequest() function:

```
function doRequest(request)
{
$.ajax(url, {
type: 'get',
data: { 'msg' : request }
});
}
```

The problem is, if I change the word value manually like value="111", I can see the value is being posted to PHP. However, when I want it to post whatever I write into textarea, it posts nothing, so the problem lies in the onSubmit area.

Can anybody help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `#` in your jQuery selectors.

```
onsubmit="doRequest($('#word').value); $('#word').value=''; return false;"
```

I would also remove the inline JavaScript and replace it with a function in the [`submit` handler](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead.  Also using [jQuery `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `.value`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
         doRequest($('#word').val());
         $('#word').val('');
         return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't enter the link on submit handler, guess the server is down. I can move this to a function, but how can I execute the function then? Under document ready function?

Comment: @Craig, I initially assumed the OP had a working function with bad selectors.  I updated it =>  it's `.val()`, not `.value`

Comment: @AnılÜnal, yes, it would simply be inside your `document.ready` function.

Comment: @Sparky672 fair enough...done the same answering a question before to, cheers.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you. Do "$('form').submit(function()" is necessary under document ready function?

Comment: @AnılÜnal, it depends on how the page loads but it certainly would not hurt to keep it within your `document.ready`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to access the value via jQuery is `val()` - not by setting a property.

```
$(...).val("set the value");
var get_the_value = $(...).val();
```

Also, your current selectors are looking for `<word>` elements which you hopefully don't have. Use `#word` as the selectors to search by ID.